# Android listvitem AsyncTask images overlapping

Tags: android, listitem

I am using listview to display data, inside listview i am using image in every listeitem.

following method is called from wrapper class

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
    ViewGroup parent) { // implementation }
```

I am following this tutorial
http://developer.android.com/guide/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List4.html

```
class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Drawable>{
        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return Util.getImageFromURL(imageURL); 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( Drawable d ) {
            getImageIcon().setImageDrawable(d);
        }

}
new DownloadImage().execute();
```

Above code performs lazy image upload for every listItem.

Problem is after loading first image images are getting overlapped on each other.... any idea why this happening ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "images are getting overlapped on each other"?  Do you mean the ListView isn't drawing correctly?  Or are all the images being shown for a single list item?

Comment: overalapping meansing one item image displaying at 2nd listitem 2nd listeitem image gone and replaced by any other listietm's image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ListView` rows get recycled. You are probably updating a row that was recycled, so the image in question is no longer valid.

In my [cwac-thumbnail](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-thumbnail) project, I put the URL in the tag of the `ImageView` and then confirm that the `ImageView` still has that tag when I go to update the image. That way, if the `ImageView` now needs a different image, I don't change it to show the wrong image.

Comment: Thanks alot gr8 implementation still i am looking to cache images.